# How to fix order of execution in NgRx Effects?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

The effect should take payload and show it in a dialog.
After the dialog IS CLOSED it should post something and dispatch a new action.

The Problem is, the action is getting dispatched before i close the dialog.

```
 @Effect()
  bookTable$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(BookTableActionTypes.BOOK_TABLE),
    map(action => action.payload),
    exhaustMap((booking: Booking) => this.dialog.open(BookTableDialogComponent, {
      width: this.window.responsiveWidth(),
      data: booking.booking,
    }).afterClosed()
      .pipe( () =>  this.bookTableService.postBooking(booking),
        map((res: any) => new BookTableSuccess(res)),
        catchError(error => of(new BookTableFail({error: error})))
      )));
```

```
.pipe( () =>  this.bookTableService.postBooking(booking),
        map((res: any) => new BookTableSuccess(res)),
        catchError(error => of(new BookTableFail({error: error})))
      )));
```

The above code should only be executed after the dialog is closed.

Comment: can you share the source code of `afterClosed` method?

Comment: I didn't implement the afterClosed() method. Its from MatDialogRef of Angular Material

Comment: If I understand it correctly you always have one `BookTableActionTypes.BOOK_TABLE` that needs to be followed by some other action that closes the dialog?

Comment: I just want the rest of the code to run as soon as the dialog is closed and not before or at the same time. Not the Action should close the dialog.

Comment: You need to fire BookTableSuccess action after the dialog is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are missing an rxjs operator inside your `pipe` for calling your API. Try `switchMap` to change the observable.

```
.pipe( 
   switchMap(() =>  this.bookTableService.postBooking(booking)),
   map((res: any) => new BookTableSuccess(res)),
   catchError(error => of(new BookTableFail({error: error})))
);
```